# Emacs ECB Method window not showing all methods

Tags: emacs, emacs-ecb

I cannot understand why I only see a few methods in ECB method window and if I click on half of shown methods, I get:

```
ECB 2.40 - Warning: The tag-visit-function `ecb-tag-visit-smart-tag-start' moves point outside of tag - ignored!
```

and cursor jump to this function:

```
void MyClass::writeLine(const char buf[]) {
send(sk,buf,strlen(buf),MSG_NOSIGNAL);
}
```

Emacs is: GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.4)

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ECB using imenu to derive your methods, then behavior will be erratic at best.  If you are using ECB with CEDET/Semantic for symbol tags, then there are many possible reasons for the missing methods.  It could be related to pre-processor symbols, or just some syntax that Semantic doesn't support yet.

Your best bet is to try the development version of CEDET to see if it fixes the issue, and if it doesn't, post an example to the mailing list and perhaps we can figure out what is broken.  The CEDET dev version is at http://cedet.sf.net.

Comment: I recompiled CEDET 1.0pre7. Issue seems to be fixed. Thanks